# Adding Characters to a Column with Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to add three 0's to the end of all entries in one column of data using an update cursor in python.  For instance, if all the entries in the column of data have a value of 123456. I need to add python code that will return 123456000.

I was able to subtract out the the last three digits to process the information originally using this:

```
    while row:
        value = row.GetValue("LD_MCPI")[:-3].strip()
        row.SetValue("LD_MCPI", value)
        rows.updateRow(row)
        row = rows.Next()
```

How can I modify the [:-3] section of the second line to yield the results I need?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What kind of object is `row`?

Comment: Are the values integers? Can you just multiply them all by 1000?

Comment: are the value string? `"123"+"000" == 123000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, `row.GetValue("LD_MCPI")` will return a string, like `"123456"`, and you want to set `value` to the string `"123456000"`.  You can do this by simply adding the string `"000"` to `row.GetValue("LD_MCPI")`:

```
value = row.GetValue("LD_MCPI") + "000"
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question.

I am pretty confident that you are dealing with strings based on the slicing you use in your example, but if `row.GetValue("LD_MCPI")` returns an int you can multiply it by 1000 to add the three zeros.

```
value = row.GetValue("LD_MCPI") * 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That was the answer I needed.